# Check if two Binary Search Tree have the same keys

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am looking for a sequential algorithm (if exists) that tests if two BST have the same keys in `O(n)`, using `O(1)` memory and recursion is allowed.
How can you do: two **synchronized** in-order trasversal,so that it is possible to compare the `ith` element of both BST?

Comment: Have _any_ of the same keys, or _all_ of the same keys?  (All is implied, but I wanted clarification)

Comment: All of the same keys

Comment: Assuming the tree has parent pointers, it is straightforward to set up an iterator object that can do an in-order traversal in O(n) time and O(1) space. So just set up one for each tree and walk them in lock-step...?

Comment: @Daniel Wagner thank you but each node has not a parent pointer .This is how It is defined a node:{int info ,node* leftchild,node* rightchild}

Comment: @anjelo In that case, I suspect you are going to have to suffer an O(log n) memory penalty to track the parents as you traverse or else a time penalty to restart the traversal many times. I doubt there's a way around it.

Comment: "*using O(1) memory but recursion is allowed*" If recursion is used, then memory is *not* O(1).

Comment: @Daniel Wagner thank you

Comment: Can you modify the trees if you put them back when you're done?

Comment: @Matt Timmermams yes you can

Comment: Are you sure about the `O(1)` memory requirement? I could design it with `O(log(n))` in space, provided that the trees are balanced

Comment: @Irleon , you can use extra memory only for the stack-frame due to the  recursion .I know how to design It with O(log(n)) memory but I want to know if It is possible or not design with O(1) memory .

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen your comment. But it was fortunate because it allowed me to discover an `O(1)` memory solution. I edited my answer and put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: Originally, I wrote this answer in `O(log(n)` for space consumption, but an `O(1)` solution, which was put afterward, is below. I prefer to keep the original context because I believe that this solution could be also useful.

In this answer, I will try to develop a way for a language without `yield`. Unfortunately, my approach uses a stack, so definitely it is not `O(1)`. If the trees are more or less balanced, the stack consumption would tend to `O(log_2(n))`.

The way as I would do it is based on an inorder iterator on a BST. It must be improved in a production environment. So, I will define the following iterator class (in a c++ pseudo language):

```
class Inorder
{
  Node * curr = nullptr; // node currentrly beeing visited
  Stack<Node*> s; // stack for storing the ancestors

  Node * advance_to_min(Node * r) // compute the leftmost node in r and stack the path
  {
    while (LLINK(r) != Node::NullPtr)
      {
        s.push(r);
        r = LLINK(r);
      }
    return r;
  }

public:

  Inorder(Node * root) : curr(advance_to_min(root)) {}

  bool has_curr() const noexcept { return curr != nullptr; }

  Node * get_curr() const { return curr; }

  void next() // get the next node inorder sense
  {
    curr = RLINK(curr);
    if (curr != nullptr)
      {
        curr = advance_to_min(curr);
        return;
      }

    if (s.is_empty())
      curr = nullptr;
    else
      curr = s.pop();
  }
};
```

The iterator above does not perform validations and assumes that the tree has at least a node. `LLINK`, `RLINK` and `KEY` are accessors to left link, right link and key, respectively.

So, with the iterator, checking if two trees contain exactly the same trees is easy:

```
bool same_keys(Node * t1, Node * t2)
{
  Inorder it1(t1), it2(t2);

  for (; it1.has_curr() and it2.has_curr(); it1.next(), it2.next())
    if (KEY(it1.get_curr()) != KEY(it2.get_curr()))
      return false;

  return not (it1.has_curr() or it2.has_curr()); 
}
```

Regarding the space consumption, I suspect this approach is equivalent to a recursive approach. However, I also suspect it exists an approach whose space consumption is strictly `O(1)`. This last would be based on "threads" temporarily put in the right null pointers in order to restore the ancestor. In a modern architecture, you could use the least significative bits of a pointer for marking whether it is or not a thread; so you do not need additional space.

**EDITED**: I had not seen an author comment saying that he already had an `O(log(n))` solution. After that, I quickly realized that my approach can be modified for iterate without a stack. So, in what follows I give an `O(1)` in space solution that uses "threads" in order to store ancestors that are successors in order sense.

First, put the following helper methods in the `Inorder` class:

```
static bool is_thread(Node * p) 
{ 
  return (Node*) (((long) p) & 1); 
}

static Node * make_thread(Node * p) 
{ 
  return (Node*) (((long)p) | 1);
}

static Node * make_pointer(Node * p)  
{ 
  return (Node*) (((long) p) & -2); 
}
```

The basic idea is using the least significant bit in order to distinguish whether a pointer is or not a thread. Note that it would not be valid to access a pointer whose least significant bit is `1`. So `is_thread()` is used in order to test whether a pointer is threaded or not. Of course, the stack is not already needed.

Now, the method `advance_to_min()` must be modified as follows:

```
static Node * advance_to_min(Node * r) // find the leftmost node respect to r
{
  Node * p = r;
  while (LLINK(p) != nullptr)
    {
      p = LLINK(p);

      Node * q = p; // searches predecessor of r inorder
      while (RLINK(q) != nullptr)
        q = RLINK(q);

      // q is the predecessor of r
      RLINK(q) = make_thread(r); // here is put the thread
      r = p;
    }

    return r;
  }
```

And the method `next()` must be refactored in order to restore the threads to null pointers. This can be done thus:

```
void next() // get the next node inorder sense
{
  if (is_thread(RLINK(curr)))
    {
      Node * p = curr;
      curr = make_pointer(RLINK(p)); 
      RLINK(p) = nullptr; // here is deleted the thread
      return;
    }

    curr = RLINK(curr);
    if (curr != nullptr)
      curr = advance_to_min(curr);
}
```

The rest of the class is the same and voila! you have an `O(1)` in space way for checking if two BST are the same keys.

Of course, it is very important that the trees are completely traversed, otherwise, the trees will be in an inconsistent state. It is sure that that will happen if the trees are different. I leave to you a cleaning routine that assures that both trees are cleaned of their threads.

Comment: Whereas it's true that your algorithm uses O(log n) extra space, any recursive algorithm also will use O(log n) extra space for stack frames. The only difference is that with the recursive version you don't see it being allocated.

Answer (score 2):

How to do this depends on your language.

In a language like Python, all you do is write the BST using `yield`.  This will create a generator that keeps a minor amount of state. (Depending on the data structure and algorithm, in this case it should be `O(1)` or `O(log(n))`.  And as we all know, in the real world `log(n)` is a constant.  Though for companies like Google it is a slightly larger constant...)

In a language without `yield` you need to arrange to create an object with state about the search with a method that you can call which will return the current element (or tell you it is done), and then move on to the next one.  Keeping state and restoring it when you enter the method is admittedly a PITA, but is under the hood what Python would have done for you.

If you wish to feel very clever, you might try automating the necessary work.  See http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html for an impressive demonstration of how to do so in C using the C preprocessor.  (This technique is actually used in a widely used program, PyTTY.)

Comment: "And as we all know, in the real world log(n) is a constant." In the real world, nobody cares about algorithmic complexity. If they're dealing with algorithmic-complexity, you have to deal with algorithmic constraints, such as log(n) not being constant.

Comment: Between computing power and expressing power I choose the expressing one. Definitely, the `yield` approach is easier.